# Elixir streaming mondodb fail

Tags: mongodb, stream, elixir

I am using elixir-mongo and trying to stream the results of a query. Here's the code...

```
def archive_stream(z) do
Stream.resource(
  fn ->
      {jobs, datetime} = z
      lt = datetime_to_bson_utc datetime
      c = jobs |> Mongo.Collection.find( %{updated_at: %{"$lt": lt}}) |> Mongo.Find.exec
      {:cont, c.response.buffer, c}
  end,
  fn(z) ->
    {j, {cont, therest, c}} = next(z)
    case cont do
      :cont -> {j, {cont, therest, c}}
      :halt  -> {:halt, {cont, therest, c}}
    end
  end,
  fn(:halt, resp) -> resp end
)
```

end

All of the sub-bits seem to work (like the query), but when I try to get at the stream, I fail...

```
Mdb.archive_stream({jobs, {{2013,11,1},{0,0,0}}})|>Enum.take(2)
```

I get...

> (BadArityError) #Function<2.49475906/2 in Mdb.archive_stream/1> with arity 2 called with 1 argument ({:cont, <<90, 44, 0, 0, 7, 95, 105, 100, 0, 82, 110, 129, 221, 102, 160, 249, 201, 109, 0, 137, 233, 4, 95, 115, 108, 117, 103, 115, 0, 51, 0, 0, 0, 2, 48, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 109, 97, 110, 97, 103, 101, 114, 45, ...>>, %Mongo.Cursor{batchSize: 0, collection: %Mongo.Collection{db: %Mongo.Db{auth: {"admin", "edd5404c4f906060b125688e26ffb281"}, mongo: %Mongo.Server{host: 'db-stage.member0.mongolayer.com', id_prefix: 57602, mode: :passive, opts: %{}, port: 27017, socket: #Port<0.27099>, timeout: 6000}, name: "db-stage", opts: %{mode: :passive, timeout: 6000}}, name: "jobs", opts: %{}}, exhausted: false, response: %Mongo.Response{buffer: <<188, 14, 0, 0, 7, 95, 105, 100, 0, 82, 110, 129, 221, 102, 160, 249, 201, 109, 0, 137, 242, 4, 95, 115, 108, 117, 103, 115, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 2, 48, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 114, 101, 116, 97, ...>>, cursorID: 3958284337526732701, decoder: &Mongo.Response.bson_decode/1, nbdoc: 101, requestID: 67280413, startingFrom: 0}}})
>       (elixir) lib/stream.ex:1020: Stream.do_resource/5
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1731: Enum.take/2

I'm stumped. Any ideas?
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang! Rookie Error.

`:halt  -> {:halt, {cont, therest, c}}` should be `_ -> {:halt, z}` and `fn(:halt, resp) -> resp end` should be `fn(resp) -> resp end`

I've been d**king around with everything but the after function for a day and a half.

A little more explanation for fellow rookies...

- the last option in the next_fun() should probably `_` inorder to catch other "bad behavior" and not just {:halt}
- the after_fn() is only expecting 1 arg and in the above code that would be the `z` tuple in the last option of the next_fun(). It is not expecting to see `:halt` and `z`, just `z`.

Would like to have REAL experts input.

Comment: You can accept your own answer so that the question will list as solved :).